# SORL-thumbnail import error in Django project

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I've installed SORL-thumbnail through `pip`. When I try to import it in the Python shell it's OK, but if I add this to INSTALLED_APPS I get:

> **ImportError** (No module named SORL)

Comment: What exactly are you adding to `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: The module name ("sorl", here) will be case-sensitive. Are you attempting to import the module in uppercase ("SORL")? If that's not it, let's see the full traceback.

Comment: might be useful for other readers. that target virtualenv might not be activated

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install sorl-thumbnail
```

Worked to me.

Notice that this package seems to have been published with a typo on the name.